# How to forEach over a whole stream after a set interval in RxJS

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have a stream of zip codes that I want to iterate over after a set interval. I'm trying to update the temperature that is shown on the page by sending the zip codes and getting the data back from the API. I have to send one at a time. So I need to be able to get all the distinct zip codes after a certain interval and iterate over the whole stream. Then I want to update the temperature on the page.

```
// Get stream of zip codes
const zipcodeStream =
  Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent(zipcodeInput, 'input')
    .map(e => e.target.value)
    .filter(zip => zip.length === 5);

// Create a timer to refresh the data
Rx.Observable
  .interval(5000)
  .zip(zipcodeStream, ([i, zip]) => zip)
  .forEach((...args) => {
    console.log('interval forEach args', ...args);
  });
```

This only sends a single zip code when a new zip code is entered and the interval has passed. I want access to them all to iterate over.

Comment: in your case **interval** won't help. as per documentation it only "Returns an observable sequence that produces **a value after each period**."( https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/interval.md).

Comment: @SufianSaory what would be the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: a quick thinking, use another interval with,say 500 ms and accumulate it's result then feed the result sequence to the main interval of 5000.

Comment: Just to clarify what you're trying to do, every 5 seconds, you want to process every item ever emitted by `zipcodeStream`, to do an API call? Or do you want to do, every 5 seconds, you search the page for a single, current zip code and do an API call for that?

Comment: @int3h I want to process every item ever emitted by `zipcodeStream` and do an API call for each one. I'll use the data that comes back from the API call to update the page accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to save all the item emitted by `zipcodeStream` so you can iterate over them every 5 seconds, you'll need to use a [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md). These save all items emitted, and replay them whenever an Observer subscribes.

In contrast, your current `zipcodeStream` Observable is a "hot" observable. This means that it starts emitting items as soon as it's created, and any subsequent subscribers will 'miss' any items emitted before they subscribed.

```
const zipcodeStream =
  Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent(zipcodeInput, 'input')
    .map(e => e.target.value)
    .filter(zip => zip.length === 5);

const zipcodeSubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject();
const zipcodeDisposable = zipcodeStream.subscribe(zipcodeSubject);

Rx.Observable
  .interval(5000)
  // Every 5000ms, will emit all items from zipcodeSubject
  .flatMapLatest(() => zipcodeSubject)
  .forEach((...args) => {
    console.log('interval forEach args', ...args);
  });
```

Comment: Only problem with this is it creates multiple subscriptions to the same ReplaySubject. So any time a new zip code is added to the `zipcodeStream`, it shows up multiple times in the output since the change propagates to each subscriber.

Comment: Good catch. Changed `flatMap` to `flatMapLatest` to avoid this. This operator unsubscribes from the previously flat mapped Observable (i.e., `zipcodeStream`), subscribes to the new Observable (i.e. resubscribes to `zipcodeStream`), then emits items only from this latest Observable.